# Cannot compile Angular project after installing a package

Tags: angular, npm

I have Installed the LocalStorage Package then I have got this message:

```
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN @angular/animations@4.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@4.1.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/common@4.0.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@4.0.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/flex-layout@2.0.0-beta.7 requires a peer of @angular/common@^2.3.5 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/flex-layout@2.0.0-beta.7 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.3.5 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/flex-layout@2.0.0-beta.7 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.0.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/flex-layout@2.0.0-beta.7 requires a peer of zone.js@^0.7.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/material@2.0.0-beta.4 requires a peer of @angular/core@^4.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN karma-jasmine@1.1.0 requires a peer of jasmine-core@* but none was installed.

+ angular-2-local-storage@1.0.1
added 2 packages, removed 580 packages and updated 1 package in 13.248s
```

So 580 packages are removed.

At the other side my Angular server stopped to work ( 404 error ) . When I tried to launch it again I have got:

```
npm start

> angular-quickstart@1.0.0 prestart /home/haddad/projects/plannerback/client/portfolio
> npm run build


> angular-quickstart@1.0.0 build /home/haddad/projects/plannerback/client/portfolio
> tsc -p src/

node_modules/@angular/animations/src/animation_metadata.d.ts(34,33): error TS1039: Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/directives/index.d.ts(8,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/directives/ng_class.d.ts(8,81): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/directives/ng_component_outlet.d.ts(8,104): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/directives/ng_for_of.d.ts(8,128): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/directives/ng_if.d.ts(8,47): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/directives/ng_plural.d.ts(8,47): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/directives/ng_style.d.ts(8,64): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/directives/ng_switch.d.ts(8,56): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/directives/ng_template_outlet.d.ts(8,73): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/location/location_strategy.d.ts(8,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/location/platform_location.d.ts(8,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.d.ts(8,75): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.d.ts(9,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs/Observable'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/pipes/case_conversion_pipes.d.ts(8,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/pipes/date_pipe.d.ts(8,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/pipes/i18n_plural_pipe.d.ts(8,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/pipes/i18n_select_pipe.d.ts(8,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/pipes/json_pipe.d.ts(8,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/pipes/number_pipe.d.ts(8,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/pipes/slice_pipe.d.ts(8,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/platform_id.d.ts(8,42): error TS1039: Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/platform_id.d.ts(9,41): error TS1039: Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/platform_id.d.ts(10,45): error TS1039: Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.
..
..
node_modules/@angular/material/typings/snack-bar/snack-bar-container.d.ts(7,37): error TS1039: Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.
node_modules/@angular/material/typings/snack-bar/snack-bar-container.d.ts(8,37): error TS1039: Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.
node_modules/@angular/material/typings/snack-bar/snack-bar-ref.d.ts(2,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs/Observable'.
node_modules/@angular/material/typings/tabs/ink-bar.d.ts(1,47): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
src/app/login.service.ts(2,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/http'.
src/app/login.service.ts(23,12): error TS7006: Parameter 'res' implicitly has an 'any' type.
src/app/modif.component.ts(1,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
src/app/modif.component.ts(2,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/router'.
src/app/modif.service.ts(1,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
src/app/modif.service.ts(2,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/http'.
src/app/modif.service.ts(5,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs/Rx'.
src/app/modif.service.ts(35,10): error TS2322: Type 'MdDialogRef<{}>' is not assignable to type 'MdDialogRef<ModifComponent>'.
 Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ModifComponent'.
   Property 'tache' is missing in type '{}'.
src/app/modif.service.ts(37,42): error TS7006: Parameter 'result' implicitly has an 'any' type.
src/app/navbar.component.ts(1,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
src/app/navbar.component.ts(2,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/router'.
src/app/signup.component.ts(1,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
src/app/signup.component.ts(2,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/router'.
src/app/signup.component.ts(3,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/http'.
src/app/signup.component.ts(22,84): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'LocalStorageService'.
src/app/tache.service.ts(1,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
src/app/tache.service.ts(2,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/http'.
src/app/tache.service.ts(5,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs/Rx'.
src/app/tache.service.ts(33,12): error TS7006: Parameter 'response' implicitly has an 'any' type.
src/app/tache.service.ts(47,14): error TS7006: Parameter 'res' implicitly has an 'any' type.
src/app/tache.service.ts(66,13): error TS7011: Function expression, which lacks return-type annotation, implicitly has an 'any' return type.
src/app/tachesEnCours.component.ts(1,35): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
src/app/tachesEnCours.component.ts(2,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/router'.
src/app/tachesInit.component.ts(1,35): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
src/app/tachesInit.component.ts(2,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/router'.
src/app/tachesTerminees.component.ts(1,35): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
src/app/tachesTerminees.component.ts(2,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/router'.
src/main.ts(1,40): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! angular-quickstart@1.0.0 build: `tsc -p src/`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/haddad/.npm/_logs/2017-06-30T16_02_12_287Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! angular-quickstart@1.0.0 prestart: `npm run build`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 prestart script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/haddad/.npm/_logs/2017-06-30T16_02_12_325Z-debug.log
```

Here is the **Log file** :

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@5.0.4
3 info using node@v7.7.2
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~prestart: angular-quickstart@1.0.0
6 verbose lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~prestart: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
7 verbose lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~prestart: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/home/haddad/projects/plannerback/client/portfolio/node_modules/.bin:/home/haddad/bin:/home/haddad/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
8 verbose lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~prestart: CWD: /home/haddad/projects/plannerback/client/portfolio
9 silly lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~prestart: Args: [ '-c', 'npm run build' ]
10 silly lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~prestart: Returned: code: 2  signal: null
11 info lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~prestart: Failed to exec prestart script
12 verbose stack Error: angular-quickstart@1.0.0 prestart: `npm run build`
12 verbose stack Exit status 2
12 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:283:16)
12 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
12 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:194:7)
12 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:40:14)
12 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
12 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:194:7)
12 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:899:16)
12 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
13 verbose pkgid angular-quickstart@1.0.0
14 verbose cwd /home/haddad/projects/plannerback/client/portfolio
15 verbose Linux 4.4.0-81-generic
16 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
17 verbose node v7.7.2
18 verbose npm  v5.0.4
19 error code ELIFECYCLE
20 error errno 2
21 error angular-quickstart@1.0.0 prestart: `npm run build`
21 error Exit status 2
22 error Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 prestart script.
22 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
23 verbose exit [ 2, true ]
```

**Package.json**

```
    {
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p src/",
    "build:watch": "tsc -p src/ -w",
    "build:e2e": "tsc -p e2e/",
    "serve": "lite-server -c=bs-config.json",
    "serve:e2e": "lite-server -c=bs-config.e2e.json",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"npm run serve\"",
    "pree2e": "npm run build:e2e",
    "e2e": "concurrently \"npm run serve:e2e\" \"npm run protractor\" --kill-others --success first",
    "preprotractor": "webdriver-manager update",
    "protractor": "protractor protractor.config.js",
    "pretest": "npm run build",
    "test": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "pretest:once": "npm run build",
    "test:once": "karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.ts -t verbose"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "^4.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "^4.1.2",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^2.0.0-beta.7",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.1.2",
    "@angular/http": "^4.1.2",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "^4.1.2",
    "angular-2-local-storage": "^1.0.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "systemjs": "^0.20.14",
    "typings": "^2.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.53",
    "@types/node": "^8.0.7",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "concurrently": "^3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.6.4",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "typescript": "^2.3.4"
  },
  "repository": {},
  "main": "karma-test-shim.js"
}
```

**Typings.json**

```
{
  "name": "webpack.typescript.react",
  "version": false,
  "dependencies": {},
  "ambientDependencies": {
    "react": "registry:dt/react#0.14.0+20160314090524",
    "react-dom": "registry:dt/react-dom#0.14.0+20160314090524"
  }
}
```

**EDIT :** After @androbin answer I add New errors :

```
node_modules/rxjs/Subject.d.ts(16,22): error TS2415: Class 'Subject<T>' incorrectly extends base class 'Observable<T>'.
  Types of property 'lift' are incompatible.
    Type '<R>(operator: Operator<T, R>) => Observable<T>' is not assignable to type '<R>(operator: Operator<T, R>) => Observable<R>'.
      Type 'Observable<T>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<R>'.
        Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'R'.
node_modules/rxjs/observable/dom/WebSocketSubject.d.ts(24,22): error TS2415: Class 'WebSocketSubject<T>' incorrectly extends base class 'AnonymousSubject<T>'.
  Types of property 'lift' are incompatible.
    Type '<R>(operator: Operator<T, R>) => WebSocketSubject<R>' is not assignable to type '<R>(operator: Operator<T, R>) => Observable<T>'.
      Type 'WebSocketSubject<R>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<T>'.
        Types of property 'operator' are incompatible.
          Type 'Operator<any, R>' is not assignable to type 'Operator<any, T>'.
            Type 'R' is not assignable to type 'T'.
src/app/boots.ts(8,55): error TS2345: Argument of type '(typeof RouterModule | typeof TacheService | typeof ModifService)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CompilerOptions | CompilerOptions[]'.
  Type '(typeof RouterModule | typeof TacheService | typeof ModifService)[]' is not assignable to type 'CompilerOptions[]'.
    Type 'typeof RouterModule | typeof TacheService | typeof ModifService' is not assignable to type 'CompilerOptions'.
      Type 'typeof RouterModule' has no properties in common with type 'CompilerOptions'.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! angular-quickstart@1.0.0 build: `tsc -p src/`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/haddad/.npm/_logs/2017-07-01T09_21_48_406Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! angular-quickstart@1.0.0 prestart: `npm run build`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 prestart script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/haddad/.npm/_logs/2017-07-01T09_21_48_436Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Can you add your tsconfig and typings files to your question please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [install](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check#install) `npm-check`. It is a very usefull application. Run it to have your dependencies updated.

Take care, the newest Angular only support typescript `2.3.4`.

If not works try to remove `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` then run the npm-check for the latest packages.

Comment: @HamzaHaddad You installed typescript@latest. After fallback is there any error?

Comment: I have installed 2.3.4 version, now there is not the same errors, I posted them

Answer (score 0):

Do not mix `@angular/*-4` and `@angular/*-2` dependencies.
Since you need `@angular/animations`, you have to update other angular-native packages (`compiler`, `forms`, `http`, 'platform-browser') to `-4` version. But that for sure will require to update all other packages to version that support angular4.

Also try to remove your `node_modules` folder and reinstall all dependencies.

Comment: Deleting `node_module` and reinstalling packages ( `npm install` ) doesn't resolve the problem. Q: How can I repair the versions of my packages ?